# Can a reaction wheel decelerate to add momentum in the same direction?

Tags: propulsion, physics, reaction-wheel, center-of-gravity

Can a reaction wheel shed weight to gain speed?

Could a reaction wheel at its max spin be flipped or rearranged around 180 degrees then slowed to add to its velocity?

Comment: Wheels need rails or roads to translate rotation in a linear movement. Or a liquid surface for a ship propeller. But you want to use a reaction wheel in zero gravity and the vacuum of space.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it obviously violates conservation of momentum physics.

Comment: The title and the body don't match. Unclear what's the question now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can a reaction wheel shed weight to gain speed?

What you need in a reaction wheel is not speed but torque. Less weight means less torque. The limit to a reaction wheel's speed is determined by motor design, friction etc. There's also a limit due to the centrifugal force in the wheel (when this force exceeds the material strength, the wheel will disintegrate), but I get the impression reaction wheels don't generally operate at those sort of speeds.

> Could a reaction wheel at its max spin be flipped around 180 degrees then slowed to add to its velocity?

No. The reaction wheel stores angular momentum. Flipping the wheel doesn't change that momentum, and doesn't allow you to increase the speed of the wheel.

Flipping the wheel will exert a large force on the axis ([the gyroscope effect](https://sciencestruck.com/what-is-gyroscopic-effect)), so you'll rotate the spacecraft as well as the reaction wheel).

Comment: This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaauRiRX4do demonstrates what happens when you try to flip a reaction wheel.